# Adding custom tags in google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using Google analytics for installation attribution for my app, and I have a URL like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Slack&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26anid%3Dadmob
```

I am wondering if I can add my own query parameters in the same URL to have something like

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Slack&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26anid%3Dadmob%26mytag%3Dtest
```

Will this potentially create issues when the play store broadcasts the intent to my receiver, and will the intent also have my own tag which I added in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test whether app receives non-utm parameters using adb command to broadcast an INSTALL_REFERRER intent as described in [testing play campaigns](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns).

```
$ cd <path_to_adb_tool>
$ echo 'am broadcast \
    -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER \
    -n "your.package.name/path.to.receiver" \
    --es "referrer" \
      "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"; \
    exit' | ./adb shell
```

Try putting custom tag for referrer and see it yourself if it reaches your `CampaignTrackingReceiver`.

As per [General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns), we can set campaign parameters from url using `setCampaignParamsFromUrl`

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName(screenName);

// In this example, campaign information is set using
// a url string with Google Analytics campaign parameters.
// Note: This is for illustrative purposes. In most cases campaign
//       information would come from an incoming Intent.
String campaignData = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?" +
    "utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer" +
    "&utm_content=email_variation_1";

// Campaign data sent with this hit.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData)
    .build()
);
```

If you have campaign information in a form other than Google Analytics campaign parameters, you will have to send it manually. One way is to use the Google Analytics web interface to configure the [custom dimension or metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets) and send it as:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("Home Screen");

// Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
// Note that the value only needs to be sent once.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setCustomDimension(1, "premiumUser")
    .build()
);
```

For [custom dimensions and metrics reporting](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#reporting) note that:

> Custom dimensions and metrics are available in custom reports and
>   available for use with advanced segments. Custom dimensions can also
>   be used as secondary dimensions in standard reports.

Comment: Thanks for answering, just one more question - Why do we need to specify the path to receiver while testing -n "your.package.name/path.to.receiver" - When the app reaches the play store, Google would not know about this path receiver until it finds the broadcast receiver receiving com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER

Comment: Its because adb test command is used offline i.e. when app is not yet published just to check if it will behave properly once it gets published.

Comment: I know that adb is offline (and the app is not published yet) , what I am asking is why does this adb require the path to the receiver (and not just the broadcast receiver handling that intent)?